# Java AWT mouse events

Tags: java, mouseevent, awt

I have an applet that makes use of the AWT event model. It has a boolean that says if the left  button is pressed or not. Here is a sample code:

```
public class Game extends Applet implements MouseListener
{
    boolean isLeftButtonPressed;

    public void init()
    {
        addMouseListener(this);
        isLeftButtonPressed = false;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("Is Button Pressed: " + isLeftButtonPressed, 20, 20);
    }

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
        isLeftButtonPressed = true;
        repaint();
}

    @Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        isLeftButtonPressed = false;
        repaint();
}

    //Other MouseListener methods not listed but have to be implemented
}
```

But it seems as if the left button is never released, even after you actually do so. What could be the problem?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this -- this site is friendly to the new users.  Especially to the ones who actually ask meaningful questions which makes sense, have enough information are well formatted.  What happened to you?

Comment: Is this question actually different from [Input Manager for Java error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529522/input-manager-for-java-error)? (I am not the down-voter, BTW.)

Comment: Same idea but compressed into a smaller format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental in this is incorrect,

These are the mouse events,

```
MousePressed ->    a mouse button is pressed
MouseReleased ->   a mouse button is released
MouseClicked ->   a mouse button is clicked (pressed and released)
```

So, when you handle the click event that means mouse is clicked and released.

So i think you have to use mousepressed instead of clicked.

[MouseEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html)

Answer (score 4):

Method `mouseClicked` will be called after `mouseReleased` method so value of  isLgetButtonPressed will be true. You have to use `MouseEvent.getButton()` method to check which mouse button is pressed.

Comment: I forgot to add that part here but it is considered (the `getButton()` method)